# View state doesn't work in cross Forms

Tags: primefaces, viewstate, jsf-2.2

I'm very new in JSF. It seems that there is a problem in JSF2 with commandButtons in a form with ajax rendering, reported in [this](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790).
A fixViewState javaScript is available for this bug, but I couldn't work with it.

I want to know if it is the absoulote solution for this case. or it really doesn't work all the time(for example with primeface commands).

Is there any other solutions?

would it be better if I wait for JSF2.3(i'm using jsf2.2 right now). And when it would be released?

thank you in advance

Comment: Don't wait for it to be solved. Use Omnifaces instead and open a new question if Omnifaces fixViewState is not working for you.

Comment: So fixViewState always works fine.thank you